# "Forbidden" error when attempting to create test through Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, content-testing

I need some help on creating Content level testing in my pages through Experience Editor. I get a "Forbidden" message when trying to create a test on a page on my website page through Experience Editor.

Issue that I am facing is :

For english language : 
I created a page in English - created a test in the IntroBanner, with 2 variants. after saving that, when i get the option for selecting the variant in the floating toolbar, in the second variant I am not getting any content. Also I get the warning in the top : "The item has a test in draft"

For danish language :
I created a page in English - created a test in the IntroBanner, with 2 variants. after saving that, i am not getting option for selecting the variant through the floating toolbar. Also i get a warning in the top : "The item has a test in draft" and "New components has been added to this page. Do you want to create a test?Create a test". When i click on Create a test, I am getting a popup which gives me "Forbidden" and also not able to create any variation through that window. (screenshots are for Danish version where i am getting error)

[image]

[image]

Also i am not able to publish this test, and this test is not available in my web database.

Please help me on the same

Comment: Is your user admin or it has some roles assigned? Which roles are assigned? Does this role or user has permissions to danish language?

Comment: can you check if you have in your browser :  403 Forbidden Status Code for some sitecore calls ?

Comment: @PeterProchazka Yes the user is admin and have access to all languages

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use and also which browser + version?

Comment: If you are on Sitecore 9, try to use latest Firefox.

Comment: Getting same issue in Azure, did you get any luck solving that? @Sreekrishnan